# Access a control without using Invoke in C#

Tags: c#

I have a form with a WebBrowser control, and an extra seperate thread that controls the browser and waits for it to load. Here's a code example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    JobClass.mainAsync();
}
```

-

```
public static class JobClass
{
    public static void mainAsync()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(main);
        t.Start();
    }

    private static void main()
    {
        Form1 frm = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
        WebBrowser wb = frm.webBrowser1;

        gotoGoogle(frm, wb);
    }

    private static void gotoGoogle(Form1 frm, WebBrowser wb)
    {
        frm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            wb.Navigate("google.com");
            string loc = wb.Document.Url.AbsolutePath;
            // ... some extra code ...
        });
    }

    private static void gotoYoutube(Form1 frm, WebBrowser wb)
    {
        frm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            wb.Navigate("youtube.com");
            wb.Document.Body.getElementById("...");
            // ... some extra code ...
        });
    }

}
```

Everything runs fine but as you see, I have to pass the `Form1` variable to each method that deals with the browser control, and I have to write `frm.Invoke()` in all of them, which makes my code less portable and more painful as the code gets bigger.

I was wondering if there's something I could do inside the "main()" method to make the `WebBrowser` maybe a child of the same thread so I don't have to keep invoking it from the form each time ? If not, how can I just get rid of this ugly invoke thing ?

Comment: see if [Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls(v=vs.110).aspx) Property helps in your case.

Comment: You accessing control from non ui thread, cant see anything ugly about invoke thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question doesn't provide enough information. It's not clear why you are even executing this code in a separate thread in the first place. The bottom line though is that if you wish to access in any way UI objects from a thread other than the UI thread, you have to use some form of `Invoke`. You can change the structure of the code to simplify this (e.g. have the `Form` instance itself do the invoking, based on some event/callback from the threaded code), but ultimately you'll have to execute that `Invoke` somewhere.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I'm executing it from a seperate thread to avoid freezing the form (UI) during Sleeps when waiting for the webBrowser to load.
I don't want any thread security as this will be the only thread accesssing the control, but I guess it's not possible ?

Comment: I don't see any calls to `Thread.Sleep()` in your question. Nor should it actually be necessary. If you were to show a _good_ code example, you could get a good answer. Unfortunately, the only answer so far isn't very good. It doesn't do anything to actually address the cross-thread issue (it seems the person who posted it may not fully understand that issue).

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following

1. define an event in your JobClass call it OnNavigationChanged
2. handle the event raise in your Form1
3. in the handled event method you can call wb.Navigate(url);

here a sample code

1- JobClass delegate

// define this delegate just above the JobClass

```
public delegate void JobClassNavigationEvent(string url);
```

2- define the event

```
public delegate void JobClassNavigationEvent(string url);
public static class JobClass
{
    public static event JobClassNavigationEvent OnNavigationChanged;
    private static BackgroundWorker worker;
    public static void mainAsync()
    {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
        {
            main();
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private static void main()
    {
        gotoGoogle();
    }

    private static void gotoGoogle()
    {
        if (OnNavigationChanged != null)
            OnNavigationChanged.Invoke("google.com");
    }

    private static void gotoYoutube()
    {
        if (OnNavigationChanged != null)
            OnNavigationChanged.Invoke("youtube.com");
    }
}
```

3- in your form

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    JobClass.OnNavigationChanged+=(url)=>{
       webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
       // other code come here
    };
    JobClass.mainAsync();
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Your code didn't do anything to solve the cross-thread invocation that's at the root of the question. For example, using `Invoke` in the anonymous event handler method.

Comment: +1. In form you need to add invoke while handling event, but this will prevent of control usage in thread and might be not that ugly(opinion-based) for OP.

Comment: Thank you. but It's not just about `webBrowser.Navigate()`. I may need to use the control for more stuff (ie: getElementById, inject javascript, get the title/location, etc..) Would this code be compatible with what I need ?

Comment: @Heidi yes, you can do your stuff in that handle function ( // other code come here )